# When is it appropriate to ask questions about Biochemistry and Chemical Biology?

Tags: discussion, scope

Biology.SE has a [similar discussion](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/136/389) but it would be good to define it here. What types of biochemistry questions are suitable for Chemistry.SE and at what point does it become a question that should be migrated to Biology.SE?

Comment: [This](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9/where-does-physics-se-end-and-chemistry-se-begin) is essentially the same question about our eastern border, and [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/would-biochemistry-questions-go-here-or-in-chemistry) is the discussion on Area 51 about this as well.

Answer (score 4):

I propose this model.

If the question is related to chemistry aspect, it will be part of Chemistry SE, where a chemist can easily understand / answer the question.

Whereas if the question is related to biological function / activity, then it will be shunted to biology SE.

In the tricky situation, 
If the question is on relation between chemistry and biology, then the author of the question is expected to clarify which part of the question s/he is more comfortable / expecting answers; and accordingly it goes to respective SE.

Comment: As this SE will deal with Chemistry, it is more likely that the answer will be closer to the chemistry aspect of the question.I think that if the question has anything to do with Chemistry, even if it is closer to Biology (or Physics), it has a place here, and deserved to be answered, if possible. A clarification request from the asker could be a good idea, as well as a suggestion to seek for a maybe better answer on Biology or Physics, besides the answer one can recieve in thie SE.